# Pre- Expanding a specific row in primefaces datatable

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

Primefaces dataTable has a feature known as expandedRow which when set to true expands all the rows.But I want only a specific row to be expanded before the dataTable loads.

```
<p:dataTable id="table" value="#{dataTable.cars}" var="car" expandedRow="true"
        paginator="true" rows="5">
        <p:column style="width:2%">
            <p:rowToggler />
        </p:column>
        <p:column id="model" headerText="Model">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column id="year" headerText="Year">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:rowExpansion >
            <h:outputText value="Manufacturer : " />
            <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />
        </p:rowExpansion>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PrimeFaces has not feature like this but you can do this via javascript. First investigate generated html code and you are going to there are div elements which has class of `.ui-row-toggler`. This element is triggering to expand content. What you need to do find this element and trigger manually.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ui-datatable-data').find('.ui-row-toggler').eq(3).trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

Put upper code after definition of your `p:dataTable` or just include js code via seperate js file. Note that `.ui-datatable-data` refers to your `p:dataTable` content.

Comment: eq(3) .. is it for the 3rd row.I put your code in the header section of my page but it was n't working. I tried debugging through firebug. The code is reached but row doesn't expand.

Comment: Yes it refers to third row. You should do that for rows that you wanted to be expanded.

Answer (score 6):

You can use expandedRow with a condition inside which is checked for every row separately.

For example:

```
expandedRow="#{car.expanded}"
```